# MappingException while trying to extends from BaseUser in FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, fosuserbundle

I'm defining an `Usuario` entity that extends from FOSUserBundle `BaseUser` and I'm do it as follow:

```
namespace UsuarioBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Misd\PhoneNumberBundle\Validator\Constraints\PhoneNumber as AssertPhoneNumber;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="usuarios_externos.usuarios", schema="usuarios_externos")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     "natural" = "Natural",
 *     "empresa" = "Empresa"
 * })
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"correo_alternativo"}, message="El correo electrónico ya está siendo usado, por favor introduzca otro.")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", timeAware=false)
 */
class Usuario extends BaseUser {
    /**
     * Hook timestampable behavior
     * updates createdAt, updatedAt fields
     */
    use TimestampableEntity;

    ...

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    ....
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> MappingException: No identifier/primary key specified for Entity
>   "UsuarioBundle\Entity\Usuario" sub class of
>   "FOS\UserBundle\Model\User". Every Entity must have an
>   identifier/primary key.

Why? Has not FOS `User` entity a [`id`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php#L25) field defined as PK?

**Weird issue while try to add field using Traits**

Since I'll have the `ID` field in many tables and for de-duplicate code and follow good practices I decide to use a Trait for it. This is how it looks:

```
namespace ComunBundle\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

trait IdentifierAutogeneratedEntityTrait {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false, unique=true)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

}
```

Now I include the trait on `Usuario` entity:

```
use ComunBundle\Model\IdentifierAutogeneratedEntityTrait;
```

And try to use in entity class:

```
class Usuario extends BaseUser {
    use IdentifierAutogeneratedEntityTrait;

    ...

}
```

Got the same error, why is not recognizing the trait?

**UPDATE**

I ran the command `doctrine:schema:validate` from Symfony2 shell and I get this output:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]   Runtime
>   Notice: FOS\UserBundle\Model\User and ComunBundle\Model\Id
>   entifierAutogeneratedEntityTrait define the same property ($id) in the
>   comp   osition of UsuarioBundle\Entity\Usuario. This might be
>   incompatibl   e, to improve maintainability consider using accessor
>   methods in traits ins   tead. Class was composed in
>   /var/www/html/sencamer/src/UsuarioBund
>   le/Entity/Usuario.php line 500

Do I need to define the `$id` in the entity and can not use a Trait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FOS User model has the id property, but is does not provide the `id` mapping to that property. You have to override the `id` property and supply the required annotation.

```
//excerpt from the FOSUserbundle doctrine mapping config
<mapped-superclass name="FOS\UserBundle\Model\User">

    <field name="username" column="username" type="string" length="255" />

    <field name="usernameCanonical" column="username_canonical" type="string" length="255" unique="true" />
```

You can see, it does not provide mapping info for the id field. You need to add it to your entity.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
```

Answer (score 2):

`FOS\UserBundle\Model\User` is a "Storage agnostic user object". Override `id` in your entity with more detailed definition:

```
/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected  $id;
```